# Expand file name, re-insert into a Properties Object

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
<%! FxDataModel FxDataModel = null;
    public void jspInit() {
    Properties fxProp = new Properties();

    ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
    String path = ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/fxRates.csv");
    fxProp.getProperty(path);
    try{
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( ctx.getRealPath( ctx.getInitParameter( FxDataModel.FX_PRP_FILE_NAME ) ) );
       // Now that you have fis you can load properties.
       fxProp.load( fis );
       // Now, you are done with fis so close it
       fis.close();
    }catch ( IOException e ) {}
    FxDataModel = new FxDataModel( fxProp );
}
%>
```

Looking at my code in NetBeans, everything seems fine.  However, when I run it i get an HTTP Status 500 error.  When I asked my professor about how to fix it he told me,

> "Apparently, fxRates.csv was not since you failed to expand the file
>   name to an absolute path with getRealPath and re-insert it into the
>   Properties object fxProp."

I'm not entirely sure what other code from my project I have to add, but I had a feeling that the error resided in this section.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You *should* have to use Servlet to read `.properties` files. Why use the `ctx.getInitParameter` method? Just try `fxProp.load(new FileInputStream(path));`

Comment: Show us the stack trace that you got with the error 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way Properties api works is similar to map

```
Properties p = new Properties()  
p.put('something','thisandthat') 
p.get('something')
```

use put to add or update a property and get to retrieve. Not sure what you wanted to do though